# Django template block item in condition if/else

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this code in `layout.html`

```
{% block createListing %}{% endblock %}
{% block listingPage %}{% endblock %}
{% block activeListings %}{% endblock %}
{% block watchlist %}{% endblock  %}
{% block Categories %}{% endblock  %}
```

Need conditional using `block` in `index.html`

```
{% if page == "CreateListing" %}
    {% block createListing %}
        <h2>Create Listing</h2>
        TODO
    {% endblock %}
{% elif page == "ActiveListings"%}
    {% block activeListings %}
            <h2>Active Listings</h2>
            TODO
        {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

Here's the thing - even with the page flag condition set to False - the block on the page still rendered!!!

It seems that the block declaration ignores/overrides the outer if statement. I don't know about you, but that was not what I expected.

I want use: (in `layout.html`)

```
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

And (in 'index.html`)

```
{% if page == "CreateListing" %}
    {% block body %}
        <h2>Create Listing</h2>
        TODO
    {% endblock %}
{% elif page == "ActiveListings"%}
    {% block body %}
            <h2>Active Listings</h2>
            TODO
        {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

And so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to mess with a conditional block body when you can do this simply:

```
{% block body %}
  {% if page == "CreateListing" %}
     <h2>Create Listing</h2>
  {% elif page == "ActiveListings"%}
     <h2>Active Listings</h2>    
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance):

> {% block %} tags are evaluated first. That’s why the content of a
> block is always overridden, regardless of the truthiness of
> surrounding tags. For example, this template will always override the
> content of the title block:

```
{% if change_title %}
    {% block title %}Hello!{% endblock title %}
{% endif %}
```

You'll need to rethink your template designs I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Template blocks are included regardless of any conditionals around them.
When the {% extends %} is being rendered, it fetches all block nodes from the template directly and stores them for rendering when the parent comes across those blocks. Whether those blocks in the child were inside conditionals or not isn't considered.
So if you must insert such blocks maybe writing like this works:

```
{% block createListing %}
    {% if page == "CreateListing" %}
        <h2>Create Listing</h2>
        TODO
    {% else %}
        Do Nothing
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

and the same way you can write it for other blocks too.